# How to make *Messages* use visual-line-mode?

Tags: hooks, visual-line-mode

I'd like to use `visual-line-mode` in the `*Messages*` buffer. I can switch to that buffer and run `M-x visual-line-mode`, but I want to configure it automatically. I've tried adding this to my init.el, but it's not taking effect:

```
(add-hook 'messages-buffer-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
```

I've also tried this, hoping it would apply `visual-line-mode` to `*Messages*` and `*Warnings*`, but again, no luck:

```
(add-hook 'special-mode-hook #'visual-line-mode)
```

Maybe it's adding the hook after the messages buffer has already been initialized? Is there a correct way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of those hooks will apply because the buffer (and its mode) has already been created long before your `add-hook` happens.

I suggest you add

```
(with-current-buffer "*Messages*"
  (visual-line-mode))
```

to your `~/.emacs` instead.